# Appending a list based on the column that the data comes from

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm attempting to append a binary numpy array to another numpy array to feed into a neural network. The binary list is dependent on the column that the array is coming from. 
For example, an array that comes from the third column is `[0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]`.

Here is an example:

Data (list of arrays):

```
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Let's say that the first two elements came from the first column of a dataframe and the third element came from the second column. After appending the binary array the data would look something like this:

```
 [([0, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]), 

([0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
[1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]), 

([1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0])]
```

For context, I was originally training on just a single column of a dataframe, however I want to be able to train over the entire dataframe now.

Is there a way to automatically append this array to my data depending on the column the data is coming from so that the neural network can train on the whole data set rather than just going column by column?

Additionally, would this require two input layers or just one?

Comment: Adding an example of what you want would help.

Comment: Edited, hope it helps a bit.

Comment: What does the dataframe look like?

Comment: The dataframe is 9 columns, each column is made up of 0's and 1's with each column being of equal length. Each entry is a single 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could add a more concrete example to your question. But anyway, is this what you're expecting?

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                           

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [[0,0,1], [1,1,1]], 'col2': [[1,1,0],[0,0,0]]})                                                                                                                    

In [3]: df                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[3]: 
        col1       col2
0  [0, 0, 1]  [1, 1, 0]
1  [1, 1, 1]  [0, 0, 0]

In [4]: for col_index, col_name in enumerate(df.columns): 
   ...:     array_to_append = [0] * len(df.columns) 
   ...:     array_to_append[col_index] = 1 
   ...:     df[col_name] = df[col_name].map(lambda x: (x, array_to_append)) 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                               

In [5]: df                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[5]: 
                  col1                 col2
0  ([0, 0, 1], [1, 0])  ([1, 1, 0], [0, 1])
1  ([1, 1, 1], [1, 0])  ([0, 0, 0], [0, 1])
```